# Rounding a double down (even when the previous calculation results in < .5)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to round the number down despite the value after the decimal point. The purpose is then to subtract the rounded number from the full number to isolate the decimals as a new value.

```
DecimalFormat decfom = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String splitter1 = decfom.format(newdecihole);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##."); 
String splitter2 = df.format(newdecihole);
double split1 = Double.parseDouble(splitter1);
double split2 = Double.parseDouble(splitter2);

double splitdeci = split1 - split2;
double finfracti = splitdeci * 8;
```

What im trying to do is turn the result into whole numbers and 8ths. Everything ive tried works fine until I have a result that rounds up instead of down (which then gives splitdeci a negative value).

Ive tried making split 2 an int but it just rounds it up

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong at the moment.

Comment: Why not use Math.floor()? double deci = Math.floor(value); double frac = value - deci;

Comment: I needed to duplicate the previous calculation into another double and have math.floor within that statement rather than trying to floor the double after double floorddeci = Math.floor(totalspriyard / convertno); –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
Math.floor
```

?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)

Comment: yeah floors still giving me the same result. calc output was 3.58 and when using the code below spl outputs as 4.0 am  I using it wrong? it sounds like it should work.
    double spl = Math.floor(split2);      
    double splitDecimal = split1 - spl;

Comment: I needed to duplicate the previous calculation into another double and  have math.floor within that statement rather than trying to floor the double after


double floorddeci = Math.floor(totalspriyard / convertno);

Answer (score 0):

```
double splitDecimal = split1 - Math.floor(split2);
int eightFraction = Math.round(splitDecimal) * 8;
```